# What is meant by the density of 10/ml?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Bacteria are inoculated in a petri dish at a density of $10/\text{ml}$. The bacteria density doubles in $20\,\mathrm{h}$. Assuming the density obeys the following ODE

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=Cx
$$
how long does it take for the density to increase to $10$ times its original value.

I only do not understand the first part. What is meant by

> Bacteria are inoculated in a petri dish at a density of $10/\text{ml}$

In other words, what information does it give if the solution of the ODE is

$$
x=x(0)e^{Cx}
$$

Comment: Well, it's phrased very obscurely...but I assume it is telling you $x(0)$.

Comment: It's telling you $x(0)$, but tell you what, I  think that value is not even required for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A density of 10/ml means there are ten bacteria per milliliter of whatever is in that Petri dish. Since the text says that $x$ is the density, it gives you $x(0)$

Comment: But note also what Olof Mellberg from Aston Villa noted in a comment under the question: This value is actually irrelevant to answering the question.

Comment: @joriki: It's irrelevant for the exercise question, but it is exactly the point of Justine Lawless' question. And you only know that it is irrelevant for the exercise question after you know the answer to Justine Lawless' question. Because if you don't know it tells you nothing about $C$, you also don't know that it is irrelevant for the exercise question.

Comment: Absolutely. I wasn't criticising your answer, just adding this note because usually information given in a problem is relevant to answering it, so the OP might have been confused otherwise.